# How can i save (and after that load) matrix in an sql database?

Tags: sql, database, image, qt, matrix

I want to save a picture represented as a matrix in my sql database. I found that using Filestream can save files (in this case pictures) in database, but i want to store directly the matrix of the image.

Comment: If you have a matrix with a variable number of columns and possibly many of them, you can encode it using in a format like json, and then save it as text.

Comment: kindly provide proper information with [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Shall i use QJsonArray class ? @DanIonescu

Comment: If your're using C++ yep, that's one way to do it @jaziri-rami